# Can we set date and time to update status from website?

Tags: php, twitter

I'm developing website that allow user to update their status to twitter timeline from my website. Currently, i can only update status to twitter timeline; but i want to set specific date and time to update status. For example, if i want to update my status at 9am; So at 9am, that status will update on twitter timeline. Does it is possible?

**My code**

```
<?php

session_start();
require_once("config/twconfig.php");
$message = "Update twitter status with specific time";
$access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
$parameters = array('status' => $message);
$status = $connection->post('statuses/update', $parameters);

?>

Thank in advance.
```

Comment: Use cronjob to run your script at specific time?

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course it is. You do want to have a look at [crontab](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference/) (Linux) or [Task Schedule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler) (Windows).